# How to clean up _variant_t

Tags: c++, com, variant

My leak checker tells me there is 2nd chance exception in this function.

```
BOOL CADORecordset::SetFieldValue(LPCTSTR lpFieldName, CString strValue)
{
    _variant_t vtFld;

    if(!strValue.IsEmpty())
        vtFld.vt = VT_BSTR;
    else
        vtFld.vt = VT_NULL;

    vtFld.bstrVal = strValue.AllocSysString();

    BOOL bret = PutFieldValue(lpFieldName, vtFld);
    SysFreeString(vtFld.bstrVal);

    return bret;
}
```

Now `_variant_t` has a type BSTR member (`bstrVal`). We [know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314307(v=vs.60).aspx) that BSTR needs to be de-allocated using `SystemFreeString()` which is what is done in the code above but since this BSTR is member of `_variant_t` who has its own destructor which cleans up, who should really clean up the `bstrVal` member in this case?

```
inline _variant_t::~_variant_t() throw()
{
    ::VariantClear(this);
}
```

It appears to me that this tries to clean up the memory again which is already cleaned up by `SysFreeString()` causing the exception? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165(v=vs.85).aspx) says it clears the variant but it is not clear what exactly it clears, does it free up the `bstrVal` as well?

If I remove the call `SysFreeString(vtFld.bstrVal);` this does remove the 2nd chance exception but I really want to know that's the right thing to do because the documentation doesn't give enough confidence.

Comment: You are helping entirely too much, never a good idea with wrapper classes like `_variant_t`.  The BSTR is getting deleted *twice*, once by you and once by variant_t.  You should not access its fields either.  All you need is `_variant_t vtFld(strValue);` or `vtFld = strValue;`, rest is automagic.

Comment: @HansPassant: Since `VT_NULL` needs to be passed to `PutFieldValue()` when `strValue` is empty, it would be more correct to use something more like this instead: `_variant_t vtFld; if(!strValue.IsEmpty()) vtFld = strValue; else vtFld.vt = VT_NULL; return PutFieldValue(lpFieldName, vtFld);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_variant_t` automatically cleans up its data when it goes out of scope.  You are manually calling `SysFreeString()`, but you are not setting `bstrVal` to NULL or setting `vt` to `VT_EMPTY` afterwards.  So, when the `variant_t` destructor calls `VariantClear()` to clean up the data, it tries to free the `bstrVal` again and crashes.

So, simply do not call `SysFreeString()` manually at all.  If you ever need to reset a `variant_t` manually, use its `Clear()` method instead:

```
vtFld.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`variant_t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx) owns its data and uses the [`VariantClear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165(v=vs.85).aspx) function for cleanup:

> The function clears a VARIANTARG by setting the vt field to VT_EMPTY. The current contents of the VARIANTARG are released first. **If the vtfield is VT_BSTR, the string is freed**. If the vtfield is VT_DISPATCH, the object is released. If the vt field has the VT_ARRAY bit set, the array is freed.

`_variant_t` is a wrapper which takes care of memory management. Similar to [`_bstr_t`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), which manages a `BSTR`; they work best together. Instead of manually setting the `vt` field and the `bstrVal` value, it's better to use the `variant_t` constructor or `operator=`. `_bstr_t` will allocate and pass `BSTR` ownership to `_variant_t`. I don't remember the details of using it. Just look up the details on MSDN.

Comment: I haven't really worked with variants that much and not so much familiar with its structure or `VARIANTARG` but it looks like what it says, it will free up the BSTR right and I don't have to call `SysFreeString(vtFld.bstrVal);`?

Comment: No, you do not need to call `SysFreeString()`, `variant_t` owns the `BSTR` and will free it for you

Comment: If you have bare C, you have to manually manage resources. For C++ special classes `_variant_t`, `_bstr_t` and another one for arrays have been provided which will do it for you.